# How to get several fields from wp_query?

Tags: wp-query, query, post-meta, terms, array

I'm going to get several fields from wp_query result. I know about wp_list_pluck() function, but it accepts only one field paramether. How to get several ones if I'd like to take several parameters from each post found?

```
[
    Object1 (ID, name, tag),
    Object2 (ID, name, tag),
    Object3 (ID, name, tag),
    etc.
]
```

Thank you for your help afterwards!

My code excerpt is here:

```
$search_param = get_param('search_param', null, 'text'); // POST param

$term_id = get_term_by('name', "$search_param", 'image_color')->term_id;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'image_color',
            'value' => sprintf( 's:%s:"%s"', strlen($term_id), $term_id ),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$hello = [
    'ID' => wp_list_pluck($query->get_posts(), 'ID'),
    'post_title' => wp_list_pluck($query->get_posts(), 'post_title')
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set 3-rd parametr for wp_list_pluck function, as i see if it's not set then there's happaning an unnessesery, for you, loop. Try to set it to true or some, not existing in Object, key.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to use wp_filter_object_list function for my case?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, yes you might, just try it and if it works than fine ))